# Tests pass in Xcode but fail on Circle CI

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, circleci, fbsnapshottestcase

**Question:** For [this pull request](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel/pull/573), the tests do not pass on CircleCI but the tests pass locally. Why?

---

The [CircleCI test output](https://circleci.com/gh/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel/82) shows failures for all `FBSnapshotTestCase` tests. For example:

> ✗ testAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth, ((comparisonSuccess__) is true) failed - Snapshot comparison failed: Error Domain=FBSnapshotTestControllerErrorDomain Code=1 "Unable to load reference image." UserInfo=0x7f85f36b0a50 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=**Reference image not found. You need to run the test in record mode**, NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to load reference image., FBReferenceImageFilePathKey=/Users/distiller/TTTAttributedLabel/Example/TTTAttributedLabelTests/ReferenceImages_32/TTTAttributedLabelTests/testAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth@2x.png}
>
> […]
>
> ✗ testAttributedTruncationToken, ((comparisonSuccess__) is true) failed - Snapshot comparison failed: Error Domain=FBSnapshotTestControllerErrorDomain Code=1 "Unable to load reference image." UserInfo=0x7f85f35b06d0 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=**Reference image not found. You need to run the test in record mode**, NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to load reference image., FBReferenceImageFilePathKey=/Users/distiller/TTTAttributedLabel/Example/TTTAttributedLabelTests/ReferenceImages_32/TTTAttributedLabelTests/testAttributedTruncationToken@2x.png}

However, the same tests pass locally:

[image]

On CircleCI the tests use the `ReferenceImages_32` directory, which does not exist:

```
/Users/distiller/TTTAttributedLabel/Example/TTTAttributedLabelTests/ReferenceImages_32/TTTAttributedLabelTests/testAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth@2x.png
```

However, the images do exist in `ReferenceImages_64`. I expect the `_64` directory to be used because the `circle.yml` file specifies to use the iPhone 6 simulator:

```
dependencies:
  pre:
    - xcrun instruments -w "iPhone 6 (8.3 Simulator)" || exit 0
  override:    
    - sudo gem install cocoapods xcpretty obcd -N
    - pod install --project-directory=Example
test:
  override:
    - set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace 'Example/Espressos.xcworkspace' -scheme 'Espressos'
      -sdk iphonesimulator -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6"
      GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS=YES GCC_GENERATE_TEST_COVERAGE_FILES=YES clean test | xcpretty -c
      --report junit --output ${CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS}/junit.xml
```

- What causes this?
- How can I get the tests passing on CircleCI?
- Possibly related: [this `FBSnapshotTestCase` issue](https://github.com/facebook/ios-snapshot-test-case/issues/102)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried running the build without the cache? This often fixes these kinds of issues for me. To build without cache, just click the button at the top right.